# How to put white circle background behind icon?

Tags: html, css

I was unsuccessful in creating a suitable Fiddle or codepen for this, so I'm hoping this information is enough within Inspector to give an idea of where I'm trying to go with this.

[This page](https://dev-dz-hamodia.pantheonsite.io/slider/) has a video slider control with thumbnails of other videos under the main video. The thumbnails have "play" icons when hovered upon. I need a way to add a white background to the icon such that the background is always underneath and not offset to the left from the icon.

Within the `.et_pb_video_play` class I tried using

```
color: #008ed4;      /* icon color */
background: #ffffff; /* background color */
border-radius: 50%;
width: 2.50rem;
height: 2.50rem;
```

for the background, but no matter what I do with `margin`, `padding`, `background-position`, `background-size`, `left`, or `top`, it seems to want to stay offset up and to the left when I need it to be exactly the same size and position as the icon.

It currently looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to align these perfectly so that just the caret in the middle of the icon is white?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: Yes. I have an icon (Elegant Themes Divi icon set) that appears on hovering over a video thumbnail. It's blue with a transparent middle "caret" triangle. I'm wanting to add a white background behind the icon so that the transparent triangle is white. But I don't want what is shown in the screenshot above where the white background is offset up and to the left from the icon. I want them to be aligned (stacked exactly on each other) so that only the triangle is white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `::before` together with `::after`.

### Example:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}

.mybtn {
    color: #008ed4;
    display: block;/* required */
    font-size: 40px;/* for font awesome or font icon size */
    height: 40px;/* required */
    left: 50%;/* for positioning on center, middle */
    position: absolute;/* for positioning on center, middle */
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);/* for positioning on center, middle */
    top: 50%;/* for positioning on center, middle */
    width: 40px;/* required */
}
.mybtn::before {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 30px;/* required, must smaller than icon size */
    left: 50%;/* required */
    position: absolute;/* required */
    top: 50%;/* required */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);/* required for center, middle white background */
    width: 30px;/* required, must smaller than icon size */
    z-index: 1;/* required for put background to bottom layer */
}
.mybtn::after {
    content: "\f144";/* for font awesome icon */
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";/* for font awesome icon */
    font-weight: 900;/* for font awesome icon */
    position: absolute;/* required */
    z-index: 2;/* required for pull icon to top layer */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bg">
    <a class="mybtn" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Both `::before` and `::after` start with their own position from the top, left of their element. You have to position them properly and use `z-index` to layer them.
The white background layer must be smaller than the icon layer to prevent it look like the borders.

[See it in action on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6s81hec5/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this simple solution in just HTML, CSS

```css
.slider-container{
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  background: #008ED4;
  border-radius:50%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.caret{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left:0.3rem;
  border-top: 1rem solid transparent;
  border-left: 2rem solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="caret"></div>
</div>
```

Also, to make any shape easily in CSS, try out [Reference](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)